# Does comment syntax exist for Oracle store procedures?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql

As table, I have

```sql
CREATE TABLE foo_tbl
(
  COLUMN1 VARCHAR2(20) 
);

COMMENT ON TABLE foo_tbl 'For look up.';
```

Is exist comment syntax for Oracle store procedure?

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE foo_user.bar_store_prod IS
BEGIN
    dbms_output.put_line('Welcome ' || 'foo');
END;
/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No.

As per the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/COMMENT.html) (21c, the latest version), a comment may only be added to the following entities:

- table
- view (materialized or not)
- column
- audit policy
- edition
- indextype
- mining model
- operator